# Чего или что?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Если что-то не расслышал и хочешь переспросить,как сказать-ЧЕГО или ЧТО?

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, что переспрашивать "Чего?" — это, во-первых, слишком уж просторечное, не далеко ушедшее от "шо?" или "че?", а во-вторых, это может носить уничижительный оттенок — переспрашивающий хочет подчеркнуть, что говорящий сморозил чушь.

Comment: Тут больше от тона, интонации и даже жестов зависит. Можно унижать, а можно показать, что до этого отвлекался, а сейчас внимательно слушаю. В письменной речи конечно лучше таких оборотов не использовать, а в устном разговоре - вполне себе применимые конструкции.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше говорить не "ЧТО?", а "Повторите, пожалуйста"

Comment: Да, лучше в вежливой форме попросить повторить. Но если выбирать из ваших вариантов, то только ЧТО (Извините, ЧТО вы сказали?)

Answer (score 0):

На практике встречал следующую дифференциацию:

"Что", если не расслышали. *Что вы сказали? *

"Чего", если расслышали, но не поняли. *Чего вы хотите?*